# Inserting arduino serial data in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, arduino

So I'm working on a project with an Arduino nano and a MAX30100 (pulse oximeter) sensor and I'm trying to insert the data in a mysql database via a python script, which I'll paste down below:

```
import serial 
import MySQLdb
import time

dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","licenta") or die ("could not connect to database")
#open a cursor to the database
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = 'COM4' #this will have to be changed to the serial port you are using
try:
  print "Trying...",device 
  arduino = serial.Serial(device, 115200) 
except: 
  print "Failed to connect on",device    

while True:
    try:
      time.sleep(5)
      data = arduino.readline()  #read the data from the arduino
      print data
      pieces = data.split('\t')  #split the data by the tab
      #Here we are going to insert the data into the Database
      try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO measurements (userid,bpm,spo2) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (1,pieces[0],pieces[1]))
        dbConn.commit() #commit the insert
        cursor.close()  #close the cursor
      except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
        print "failed to insert data"
      finally:
        cursor.close()  #close just incase it failed
    except:
      print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
```

Now the problem that I have is that it only inserts the first value that it reads, and by the time it reads the second value I keep getting the "Failed to get data from Arduino!" and they are not inserted into the DB. Also, after reading the first value I get this warning:

> Warning (from warnings module):
> File "C:\xampp\htdocs\send_to_db.py", line 24
> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO measurements (userid,bpm,spo2) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (1,pieces[0],pieces[1]))
> Warning: Data truncated for column 'spo2' at row 1

Though this warning doesn't seem to affect the data itself.
Any suggestions?
Later edit: here's the arduino code, if it matters:

```
/*
Arduino-MAX30100 oximetry / heart rate integrated sensor library
Copyright (C) 2016  OXullo Intersecans <x@brainrapers.org>

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"

#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS     5000

// PulseOximeter is the higher level interface to the sensor
// it offers:
//  * beat detection reporting
//  * heart rate calculation
//  * SpO2 (oxidation level) calculation
PulseOximeter pox;

uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;

// Callback (registered below) fired when a pulse is detected
void onBeatDetected()
{
    Serial.println("Beat!");
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    //Serial.print("Initializing pulse oximeter..");

    // Initialize the PulseOximeter instance
    // Failures are generally due to an improper I2C wiring, missing power supply
    // or wrong target chip
    if (!pox.begin()) {
        //Serial.println("FAILED");
        for(;;);
    } else {
        //Serial.println("SUCCESS");
    }

    // The default current for the IR LED is 50mA and it could be changed
    //   by uncommenting the following line. Check MAX30100_Registers.h for all the
    //   available options.
    // pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);

    // Register a callback for the beat detection
    //pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
}

void loop()
{
    // Make sure to call update as fast as possible
    pox.update();

    // Asynchronously dump heart rate and oxidation levels to the serial
    // For both, a value of 0 means "invalid"
    if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
        //Serial.print("Heart rate:");
        Serial.print(pox.getHeartRate());
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(pox.getSpO2());
        Serial.println('\t');

        tsLastReport = millis();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the setting of `autocommit`?  Do you perform `START TRANSACTION`?

Comment: You closed your database cursor at the end of the loop, on the second time, there is no database cursor open for writing the data to the database.

Comment: Rick, I'm a beginner when it comes to python and arduino programming so I don't know what either of those mean.